# In python while using list.remove(value_of_the_list) a ValueError is thrown

Tags: python, list, items

While clearing some values from the global variable of type list via list.remove(value) function, I get an error `"ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list"`

My class definition looks like this:

```
class Deck(object):
global_l_init = ['2h','2d','2s','2c','3h','3d','3s','3c','4h','4d','4s','4c',
'5h','5d','5s','5c','6h','6d','6s','6c','7h','7d','7s','7c',
'8h','8d','8s','8c','9h','9d','9s','9c','10h','10d','10s','10c',
'Jh','Jd','Js','Jc','Qh','Qd','Qs','Qc','Kh','Kd','Ks','Kc',
'Ah','Ad','As','Ac']
#Cards' value
d={'2h':2,'2d':2,'2s':2,'2c':2,'3h':3,'3d':3,'3s':3,'3c':3,
   '4h':4,'4d':4,'4s':4,'4c':4,'5h':5,'5d':5,'5s':5,'5c':5,
   '6h':6,'6d':6,'6s':6,'6c':6,'7h':7,'7d':7,'7s':7,'7c':7,
'8h':8,'8d':8,'8s':8,'8c':8,'9h':9,'9d':9,'9s':9,'9c':9,
'10h':10,'10d':10,'10s':10,'10c':10,'Jh':10,'Jd':10,'Js':10,
'Jc':10,'Qh':10,'Qd':10,'Qs':10,'Qc':10,'Kh':10,'Kd':10,'Ks':10,'Kc':10,
'Ah':10,'Ad':10,'As':10,'Ac':10,'Ah':1,'Ad':1,'As':1,'Ac':1}

def __init__(self,plr_cur_value):
    self.plr_cur_value = plr_cur_value

def deck_change(self):
    self.global_l_init.remove(self.plr_cur_value)
```

What I do to check how it works, is:

```
D1=Deck(['2h','Jh'])
D1.deck_change()
```

The error is as follows:

```
  ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-534-6f04c0ca0556> in <module>()
      1 D1=Deck(['2h','Jh'])
----> 2 D1.deck_change()

<ipython-input-528-7691239e1d5b> in deck_change(self)
     54 
     55     def deck_change(self):
---> 56         self.global_l_init.remove(self.plr_cur_value)
     57 

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I am new to python. Maybe the question is stupid enough. But still cannot figure out why `global_l_init` defined as class variable is not accessed/changed?...
Appreciate your answers.

Comment: All your decks share the same `global_l_init` variable. If you modify it in one deck, it affects all the rest.

Comment: How does checking `D1.plr_cur_value` tell you whether the value is in the list?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. And I do need to change the Global list of deck. Well, actually currently there is only one deck (maybe I chose not a proper name, but it doesn't matter now). I just cannot realize why remove() doesn't work when the value does exist in the list...

Comment: But it doesn't, because you've already removed it.

Comment: Well, I call D1.plr_cur_value and then check D1.global_l_init. the value is still there. Then I call D1.deck_change()...

Comment: Show your code that's doing the check.

Comment: The best thing to do before posting a question is to print every single unknown on every single line so you can see as much useful info as possible.

Comment: `self.global_l_init` is not the same as `Deck.global_l_init`.

Comment: I may assume that the error is Deck.global_l_init is to be used instead of self.global_l_init. But it changes nothing.. I still have same error.

Comment: @Barmar: If you never bind anything to `self.global_l_init`, then it will be the same as `Deck.global_l_init`. Given the name, I assume the intent was for `global_l_init` to be a class variable shared by multiple `Deck` instances (though the why eludes me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the code you've provided, you've got a logic error between what `remove` expects (a single item to remove from the `list`) and what you're giving it (a `list` of items).

You initialize your instance with:

```
D1=Deck(['2h','Jh'])
```

so `self.plr_cur_value` is `['2h','Jh']`, which means your `remove` call is equivalent to:

```
self.global_l_init.remove(['2h','Jh'])
```

`remove` looks through your `global_l_init` `list` (which only has length 2 `str` in it), trying to see if it contains a length 2 `list` of length 2 `str` (which it doesn't, it doesn't contain any `list`s at all).

If the goal is to remove each of the elements from `global_l_init`, you need to change:

```
self.global_l_init.remove(self.plr_cur_value)
```

to:

```
for card in self.plr_cur_value:
    self.global_l_init.remove(card)
```

to make it remove each card individually.

Note that `list` is a suboptimal data structure when you need to repeatedly perform membership testing (`O(n)`), or perform random access `list` insertions or removals (`O(n)` each). Since all your values are unique and order-insensitive, you'd be better off using a `set` here, which has `O(1)` insertion, deletion and membership testing:

```
class Deck(object):
    #Cards' value
    d={'2h':2,'2d':2,'2s':2,'2c':2,'3h':3,'3d':3,'3s':3,'3c':3,
       '4h':4,'4d':4,'4s':4,'4c':4,'5h':5,'5d':5,'5s':5,'5c':5,
       '6h':6,'6d':6,'6s':6,'6c':6,'7h':7,'7d':7,'7s':7,'7c':7,
    '8h':8,'8d':8,'8s':8,'8c':8,'9h':9,'9d':9,'9s':9,'9c':9,
    '10h':10,'10d':10,'10s':10,'10c':10,'Jh':10,'Jd':10,'Js':10,
    'Jc':10,'Qh':10,'Qd':10,'Qs':10,'Qc':10,'Kh':10,'Kd':10,'Ks':10,'Kc':10,
    'Ah':10,'Ad':10,'As':10,'Ac':10,'Ah':1,'Ad':1,'As':1,'Ac':1}

    # Simplest way to make set here is to reuse d to make global_l_init w/o repeating yourself:
    global_l_init = set(d)

    def __init__(self,plr_cur_value):
        self.plr_cur_value = set(plr_cur_value)  # Convert to set on initialization

    def deck_change(self):
        # Optionally, make sure the cards are in the shared set before removing them
        # to match list.remove behavior of raising ValueError when card not found
        if not (self.plr_cur_value <= self.global_l_init):
            raise ValueError("Cards in hand are not in the deck: {}".format(
                    ', '.join(self.plr_cur_value - self.global_l_init)))

        # Bulk remove entire hand now that we know it's available
        self.global_l_init -= self.plr_cur_value
```

Comment: thank you for your effort. I got it. I spent too much time with the code and lost the focus, didn't see the wood for the trees. I missed that part that plr_cur_value can get not only ONE value of a list.